# How to master keyboard language on iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard, internationalization, language

There seems to be something wrong with the language switching on iOS. I have 3 keyboards/languages setup in this order: Dutch - English - Emoji. In certain applications, when I am typing a message in Dutch, and I press the globe icon, it takes me to the last used keyboard. This is ok.

But, When I use e.g. an app like hangouts, where I have a external send button, every time I send a message from the Emoji keyboard, the keyboard reverts to another language. Sometimes this is Dutch, sometimes this is English. It seems to revert to the last **globally** used keyboard, instead of the last **in-app** keyboard. This is really annoying and feels counter intuitive when using the key-board.

Does anyone have more insight in how the keyboard switch and how to use them properly with multiple languages?

Comment: Do you find behavior to be consistent among Apple apps (e.g. Mail, Safari, Messages, Notes, Pages)?

Comment: The only way I've found to have more control on the same situation is to keep the globe pressed and choose from the list. Just pressing to rotate gives me the same erratic behavior.